# how to coalesce timestamp with not null constraint postgres

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, coalesce, notnull

```
insert into employee(eid,dojo) SELECT
    14,coalesce(to_char(dojo,'dd-mm-yyyy'),'')  
        from employee;
```

I have to insert into table by selecting it from table,my column dojo has not null constraint and timestamp doesn't allow '' to insert please provide an alternate for this if timestamp is null from select query

Comment: ERROR: invalid input syntax for type timestamp: ""
 Line: 1

Comment: It shows me that error when i try to insert, i know coz timestamp doesnt allow ''

Comment: Please show us data from the `dojo` column.  You're currently trying to insert character data as a timestamp.

Comment: 19/2/1995 12:00:00 PM .

Comment: im inserting timestamp into dojo unless its null i want it to be empty but not using now()

Comment: `''` is not a valid timestamp value. And if you want the value to be "empty" the only choice you have is `null`

Comment: but bro it has a not null constraint and i cannot enter any other date

Comment: Wanting them to be empty contradicts the fact that you have not null constraint on that field. It just won't work that way. Remove the not null constraint, it is the only way (and don't use `coalesce` ofc).

Answer (score 3):

Your current query has severals problems, two of which I think my answer can resolve.  First, you are trying to insert an empty string `''` to handle `NULL` values in the `dojo` column.  This won't work, because empty string is not a valid timestamp.  As others have pointed out, one solution would be to use `current_timestamp` as a placeholder.

Another problem you have is that you are incorrectly using `to_char` to format your timestamp data.  The output of `to_char` is a string, and the way you are using it would cause Postgres to reject it.  Instead, you should be using `to_timestamp()`, which can parse a string and return a timestamp.  Something like the following is what I believe you intend to do:

```
insert into employee (eid, dojo)
select 14, coalesce(to_timestamp(dojo, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS PM'), current_timestamp)
from employee;
```

This assumes that your timestamp data is formatted as follows:

```
DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS PM   (e.g. 19/2/1995 12:00:00 PM)
```

It also is not clear to me why you are inserting back into the `employee` table which has non usable data, rather than inserting into a new table.  If you choose to reuse `employee` you might want to scrub away the bad data later.

Comment: The employee from select query is in other database and insertion is into other database,both tables have got same name and structure

Comment: @DragonWarrior Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Newbie bro!!! function to_timestamp(date, unknown) does not exist
 Line: 1

Comment: im getting this error when im  trying to run ur query

Comment: What version of Postgres are you using?

Comment: PostgreSQL 9.3.13 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-16), 64-bit

Answer (score 0):

you can use some default date value like 1st jan 1900 or `now()`
your query should be like

```
 insert into employee(eid,dojo) SELECT
    14,coalesce(to_char(dojo,'dd-mm-yyyy'),now())  
        from employee;
```

Comment: Inserting `dd-mm-yyyy` as a timestamp doesn't seem right to me.

Comment: I dont want to insert values if it is null but want column to b empty

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I was about to write him but then think if I am not wrong from the code style he is from oracle background so I let it as it is.

Comment: @DragonWarrior you can't keep the column blank incase of time stamp with not null constraint

Comment: what could be an alternative to that

Comment: You can do one thing if this is the requirement then my solution would be change the data type of the column from timestamp to text and keep the data at the time of insertion or representation cast it accordingly.

Comment: Im dealing with sensitive data!!! i cant manipulate it using now(),that is the reason i want it to be empty or something else.

Comment: so then give some default past date like I mentioned and make an exception in your procedure whenever that date appears  just ignore it.

Comment: @DragonWarrior: `null` **is** "empty" for a timestamp column

Answer (score -2):

There is no such thing as a non-null yet blank timestamp. NULL = blank.

There is literally nothing you can do but store a valid timestamp or a null. Since you have a non-null constraint your only option is to pick a default timestamp that you consider "blank".

Using a hard coded date to indicate a blank value is a terrible terrible terrible idea btw. If it is blank, remove the not null constraint, make it null and move on.

I am not trying to be condescending but I do not think you understand nulls. See here

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_(SQL)